# How to find "Eastern" most point of Regions Located Within Wrapping 2-d Plane

Tags: algorithm, matrix, 2d

I am attempting to figure a way to determine the furthest square (eastern-most, western-most etc.) of a contiguous region existing on a wrapping 2-d plane. The bottom-left point is [0,0] and the top-right is, for example, [244,244] I've included an example of my data below. Notice the dark grey region that is present in the 4 corners is the same region.

[image]

I was able to solve this problem with my data by checking each square within a given region and recording which has the highest X. I also did the same search, except restricted to [0,width * .5]. However, this solution only works because my regions are mostly centered around a point and not long and thin.

@maraca outlined a method in the comments which I think can be distilled down to:

```
* find an edge square
* assign 0 to current square
* walk around the edges, adding 1 when travelling east, -1 when travelling west (or north/ south) 
* the square with the highest value is the furthest east, the square with the lowest value is the furthest west
```

Comment: You have not specified how your data (regions) is organized.

Comment: Can't you just find the northern and southern point and then walk around the border in both directions. You then know that the western point can be found by going to the left from the northern point until the southern point is reached. Instead of using the real coordinates to keep track of the minimum in x direction just count the number of steps you went to the left in relation to the northern point and then take the point with the most steps to the left.  You could do this for all the extreme points, just start somewhere on the border, walk around it and track steps in all directions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@maraca outlined a method in the comments which I think can be distilled down to:

```
* find an edge square
* assign 0 to current square
* walk around the edges, adding 1 when travelling east, -1 when travelling west (or north/ south) 
* the square with the highest value is the furthest east, the square with the lowest value is the furthest west
```

It works great. Thanks!